# calling javafunction from jfidle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really having a difficult time runnning Javascript functions.

I have this simple function entered in jfiddle.

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }



    var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

and I would like to call it from the console, I tried:

I have tried various ways of calling the function Makefunc(), but none of it worked.

and when I checked for the name variable, it gives me result instead of "Mozzilla". How come?

```
>>> myFunc();
ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
undefined
>>> myFunc()
ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
undefined
>>> displayName
ReferenceError: displayName is not defined
undefined
>>> displayName()
ReferenceError: displayName is not defined
undefined
>>> makeFunc();
ReferenceError: makeFunc is not defined
undefined
>>> makeFunc()
ReferenceError: makeFunc is not defined
undefined
>>> name
"result"
>>> alert(name);
undefined
>>> myFunc
ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
undefined
>>> myFunc();
ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
undefined
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `}` to close the `makeFunc` function. You also need to return something from `makeFunc` or it's always going to return `undefined`.

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  return function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
}


var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

Comment: what do u mean by it should return something, doesnt it return displayName()

Comment: You have no `return` anywhere in your code, so no, nothing is being returned.